# How to print void function after cout statement?

Tags: c++, function, fractions

I'm trying to print the output of the function after my values are sent to the function. The cout statement needs a string but I'm not sure how I can return a string from my reduce_fraction function while keeping the math correct. In my add_fraction function, you'll see that I simply want to print the added fraction then the reduced fraction right below it. The compiler returns no errors but the output just shows the "Improper Fraction" answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


 void reduce_fraction (int top, int bottom)
 {
    for (int i = top * bottom; i > 1; i--) {  
            if ((top % i == 0) && (bottom % i == 0)) {  
         bottom /= i;  
            top /= i;  
    }  

     }
}

void add_fraction (int numerator, int numerator2, int denominator, int              
denominator2)
{
int top;
int bottom;
top = numerator2 * denominator + denominator2 * numerator;
bottom = denominator2 * denominator;

cout << "Improper Fraction -> ";
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;
cout << "Simplified Fraction -> ";
reduce_fraction(top, bottom);
}


int main()
{

int numerator;
int denominator;
int numerator2;
int denominator2;
char operation;

cout << "Input the numerator: ";
cin >> numerator;

cout << "Input the denominator: ";
cin >> denominator;

cout << "Input the numerator2: ";
cin >> numerator2;

cout << "Input the denominator: ";
cin >> denominator2;

cout << "Input the operation: ";
cin >> operation;

if (operation == '+'){
    add_fraction(numerator, numerator2, denominator, denominator2);
}

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You can't return *anything* from `reduce_fraction`; that's what it means to have a `void` function.

Comment: Yeah, but can I pull the top and bottom variable that I sent from add_fraction into reduce_fraction then print the results somehow?

Comment: You could if you passed them by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *reference* to reflect the changes in `top` and `bottom`
and print those in your `add_fraction` function after calling `reduce_fraction`

```
void reduce_fraction ( int & top, int & bottom)
{                         ~~~        ~~~
 //...
}
```

Then,

```
reduce_fraction(top, bottom);
cout << top << "/" << bottom << endl;
```

Comment: Would still need something to actually, you know, print them.

Comment: Ahh, this worked. So the & character essentially updates the integers based on what happened in the function?

Comment: @austinscode: That would be too simple. In this context the character combines to produce `int&`. That is a **refererence** to an `int`. In particular, it means that `int& top` is not a variable itself, but merely a new name for the first variable passed to `reduce_fraction`.